# Not annotated parameter overrides @NonNull parameter

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-fragments, android-intent

@nonnull error at inflater ,  any one can solve this error? 
im new to android i don't know how to solve this error any solution ? 
is it the error of due theme or something else ,do my code have some major issue ?? can you solve this error please. due to this error my code is not working. your help will be highly appreciated

my import in the code is listed below

```
       import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.View;
import android.app.DownloadManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.support.v7.widget.DividerItemDecoration;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.util.List;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.util.Log;
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import static android.content.Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE;
import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.io.StringWriter;
import java.io.Writer;
import java.lang.ref.WeakReference;
import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;



 public class FilesListingFragment extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {


    private static final String TAG = "FilesListingFragment";

    public static final String PATH_FILES = "http://%s:%s/files";
    public static final String PATH_STATUS = "http://%s:%s/status";
    public static final String PATH_FILE_DOWNLOAD = "http://%s:%s/file/%s";

    private String mSenderIp = null, mSenderSSID;
    private ContactSenderAPITask mUrlsTask;
    private ContactSenderAPITask mStatusCheckTask;

    private String mPort, mSenderName;

    static final int CHECK_SENDER_STATUS = 100;
    static final int SENDER_DATA_FETCH = 101;

    RecyclerView file;
    ProgressBar progressBar;
    TextView mTextView;

    private SenderFilesListingAdapter mFilesAdapter;

    private UiUpdateHandler uiUpdateHandler;

    private static final int SENDER_DATA_FETCH_RETRY_LIMIT = 3;
    private int senderDownloadsFetchRetry = SENDER_DATA_FETCH_RETRY_LIMIT, senderStatusCheckRetryLimit = SENDER_DATA_FETCH_RETRY_LIMIT;

    @Nullable

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_files_listing, null);
        file = (RecyclerView) v.findViewById(R.id.files_list);
        progressBar = (ProgressBar) v.findViewById(R.id.loading);
        mTextView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.empty_listing_text);
        mTextView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                mTextView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                fetchSenderFiles();
            }
        });
        file.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
        file.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.lidivider)));/**here is the error */
        mFilesAdapter = new SenderFilesListingAdapter(new ArrayList<String>());
        file.setAdapter(mFilesAdapter);
        uiUpdateHandler = new UiUpdateHandler(this);
        return v;
    }

    public static FilesListingFragment getInstance(String senderIp, String ssid, String senderName, String port) {
        FilesListingFragment fragment = new FilesListingFragment();
        Bundle data = new Bundle();
        data.putString("senderIp", senderIp);
        data.putString("ssid", ssid);
        data.putString("name", senderName);
        data.putString("port", port);
        fragment.setArguments(data);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        if (null != getArguments()) {
            mSenderIp = getArguments().getString("senderIp");
            mSenderSSID = getArguments().getString("ssid");
            mPort = getArguments().getString("port");
            mSenderName = getArguments().getString("name");
            Log.d(TAG, "sender ip: " + mSenderIp);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        fetchSenderFiles();
        checkSenderAPIAvailablity();
    }

    private void fetchSenderFiles() {
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        if (null != mUrlsTask)
            mUrlsTask.cancel(true);
        mUrlsTask = new ContactSenderAPITask(SENDER_DATA_FETCH);
        mUrlsTask.execute(String.format(PATH_FILES, mSenderIp, mPort));
    }

    private void checkSenderAPIAvailablity() {
        if (null != mStatusCheckTask)
            mStatusCheckTask.cancel(true);
        mStatusCheckTask = new ContactSenderAPITask(CHECK_SENDER_STATUS);
        mStatusCheckTask.execute(String.format(PATH_STATUS, mSenderIp, mPort));
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if (null != mUrlsTask)
            mUrlsTask.cancel(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (null != uiUpdateHandler)
            uiUpdateHandler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
        if (null != mStatusCheckTask)
            mStatusCheckTask.cancel(true);
    }

    public String getSenderSSID() {
        return mSenderSSID;
    }

    public String getSenderIp() {
        return mSenderIp;
    }

    private void loadListing(String contentAsString) {
        Type collectionType = new TypeToken<List<String>>() {
        }.getType();
        ArrayList<String> files = new Gson().fromJson(contentAsString, collectionType);
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        if (null == files || files.size() == 0) {
            mTextView.setText("No Downloads found.\n Tap to Retry");
            mTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            mTextView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            mFilesAdapter.updateData(files);
        }
    }

    private void onDataFetchError() {
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        mTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mTextView.setText("Error occurred while fetching data.\n Tap to Retry");
    }

    private long postDownloadRequestToDM(Uri uri, String fileName) {

        // Create request for android download manager
        DownloadManager downloadManager = (DownloadManager) getActivity().getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
        DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(uri);


        request.setTitle(fileName);

        request.setDescription("ShareThem");
        request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);


        request.setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(getActivity(),
                Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, fileName);

        return downloadManager.enqueue(request);
    }

    private class SenderFilesListingAdapter extends RecyclerViewArrayAdapter<String, SenderFilesListItemHolder> {
        SenderFilesListingAdapter(List<String> objects) {
            super(objects);
        }

        void updateData(List<String> objects) {
            clear();

            mObjects = objects;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public SenderFilesListItemHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).


                    inflate(R.layout.listitem_file, parent, false);
            return new SenderFilesListItemHolder(itemView);
        }


        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(SenderFilesListItemHolder holder, int position) {
            final String senderFile = mObjects.get(position);
            holder.itemView.setTag(senderFile);
            final String fileName = senderFile.substring(senderFile.lastIndexOf('/') + 1, senderFile.length());
            holder.title.setText(fileName);
            holder.download.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    postDownloadRequestToDM(Uri.parse(String.format(PATH_FILE_DOWNLOAD, mSenderIp, mPort, mObjects.indexOf(senderFile))), fileName);
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Downloading " + fileName + "...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        }
    }

    static class SenderFilesListItemHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView title;
        ImageButton download;

        SenderFilesListItemHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.sender_list_item_name);
            download = (ImageButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.sender_list_start_download);
        }
    }


    /**
     * Performs network calls to fetch data/status from Sender.
     * Retries on error for times bases on values of {@link FilesListingFragment#senderDownloadsFetchRetry}
     */
    private class ContactSenderAPITask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        int mode;
        boolean error;

        ContactSenderAPITask(int mode) {
            this.mode = mode;
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
            error = false;
            try {
                return downloadDataFromSender(urls[0]);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                error = true;
                Log.e(TAG, "Exception: " + e.getMessage());
                return null;
            }
        }

        // onPostExecute displays the results of the AsyncTask.
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            switch (mode) {
                case SENDER_DATA_FETCH:
                    if (error) {
                        if (senderDownloadsFetchRetry >= 0) {
                            --senderDownloadsFetchRetry;
                            if (getView() == null || getActivity() == null || null == uiUpdateHandler)
                                return;
                            uiUpdateHandler.removeMessages(SENDER_DATA_FETCH);
                            uiUpdateHandler.sendMessageDelayed(uiUpdateHandler.obtainMessage(mode), 800);
                            return;
                        } else senderDownloadsFetchRetry = SENDER_DATA_FETCH_RETRY_LIMIT;
                        if (null != getView())
                            onDataFetchError();
                    } else if (null != getView())
                        loadListing(result);
                    else Log.e(TAG, "fragment may have been removed, File fetch");
                    break;
                case CHECK_SENDER_STATUS:
                    if (error) {
                        if (senderStatusCheckRetryLimit > 1) {
                            --senderStatusCheckRetryLimit;
                            uiUpdateHandler.removeMessages(CHECK_SENDER_STATUS);
                            uiUpdateHandler.sendMessageDelayed(uiUpdateHandler.obtainMessage(CHECK_SENDER_STATUS), 800);
                        } else if (getActivity() instanceof ReceiverActivity) {
                            senderStatusCheckRetryLimit = SENDER_DATA_FETCH_RETRY_LIMIT;
                            ((ReceiverActivity) getActivity()).resetSenderSearch();
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), getString(R.string.p2p_receiver_error_sender_disconnected), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        } else
                            Log.e(TAG, "Activity is not instance of ReceiverActivity");
                    } else if (null != getView()) {
                        senderStatusCheckRetryLimit = SENDER_DATA_FETCH_RETRY_LIMIT;
                        uiUpdateHandler.removeMessages(CHECK_SENDER_STATUS);
                        uiUpdateHandler.sendMessageDelayed(uiUpdateHandler.obtainMessage(CHECK_SENDER_STATUS), 1000);
                    } else
                        Log.e(TAG, "fragment may have been removed: Sender api check");
                    break;
            }

        }

        private String downloadDataFromSender(String apiUrl) throws IOException {
            InputStream is = null;
            try {
                URL url = new URL(apiUrl);
                HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                conn.setReadTimeout(10000 /* milliseconds */);
                conn.setConnectTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
                conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
                conn.setDoInput(true);
                // Starts the query
                conn.connect();
               int response =
                conn.getResponseCode();
               Log.d(TAG, "The response is: " + response);
                is = conn.getInputStream();
                // Convert the InputStream into a string
                return readIt(is);
            } finally {
                if (is != null) {
                    is.close();
                }
            }
        }

        private String readIt(InputStream stream) throws IOException {
            Writer writer = new StringWriter();

            char[] buffer = new char[1024];
            try {
                Reader reader = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(stream, "UTF-8"));
                int n;
                while ((n = reader.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                    writer.write(buffer, 0, n);
                }
            } finally {
                stream.close();
            }
            return writer.toString();
        }
    }
    private static class UiUpdateHandler extends Handler {
        WeakReference<FilesListingFragment> mFragment;

        UiUpdateHandler(FilesListingFragment fragment) {
            mFragment = new WeakReference<>(fragment);
        }

        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            FilesListingFragment fragment = mFragment.get();
            if (null == mFragment)
                return;
            switch (msg.what) {
                case CHECK_SENDER_STATUS:
                    fragment.checkSenderAPIAvailablity();
                    break;
                case SENDER_DATA_FETCH:
                    fragment.fetchSenderFiles();
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

**fragment_files_listing**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".receiver.FilesListingFragment"

    >

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/files_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" />

    <ProgressBar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        style="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ProgressBar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/loading"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />

    <TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/empty_listing_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="No Downloads found.\n Tap to Retry"
        android:visibility="gone" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: on which line error is shown ?

Comment: Please, share your log and your `R.layout.fragment_files_listing` xml file

Comment: @ferran take a look on xml

Comment: at this line error is shown                                                                         
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)

Comment: i think due to this error there is one more take a look on it                                                      [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55990560/divideritemdecoration-android-content-context-int-in-divideritemdecoration-ca)

Comment: See my answer...

Answer (score 2):

> Not annotated parameter overrides @NonNull parameter

This is just a warning. You have

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater...
```

while the base class you're extending has nullity annotation on the inflater parameter.

```
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater...
```

You can just alt-enter in Android Studio to get a quick fix menu that has the option to add the missing annotation there.

> due to this error my code is not working.

Missing an annotation like that just causes a warning. The reason for "not working" is something else. Please start by updating your question and specifying what "not working" means to you here.

Comment: maybe due to this error my code  is not working take a look [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55990560/divideritemdecoration-android-content-context-int-in-divideritemdecoration-ca)

Answer (score 0):

Try to change this line

```
View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_files_listing, null);
```

to

```
View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_files_listing, container, false);
```

This will inflate your layout with your fragment container.

Comment: maybe due to this error my code  is not working take a look [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55990560/divideritemdecoration-android-content-context-int-in-divideritemdecoration-ca)

Answer (score 0):

You have to change this line

```
View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_files_listing, null);
```

to

```
View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_files_listing, container, false);
```

and then clean your project and invalidate cache restart you android studio.